# Migrating from MongoDB Atlas to self managed Mongo (EC2) server

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

There is an abundance of info about migrating TO Atlas but not too much I could find specifically about going the other direction.

I am migrating a collection which is 250GB in size. 
I have tried using mongodump from the remote EC2 server connecting to the Mongo Atlas instance however presumably due to the large collection size this keeps failing.
I have also read that mongodump is not great for DBs of this size but I could be wrong.

I was able to download a backup .tar.gz file from Atlas and move this to the the remove server. The file contents are below.

Is it possible to restore these in to a fresh mongo setup on the EC2, or will these only work for the environment they were taken from?

Here are the files available in the backup:

[image]

Comment: You can use a backup of your data files with a standalone deployment, but should be using the same major release of MongoDB server (eg 4.0.x) as used on the deployment the backup files were copied from.

Answer (score 1):

These appear to be database files, if you move them to the Mongodb [data path](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath), then start the mongod process/service, should work.

If the database is **not inside sharded clusters**, you can use mongodump/mongorestore.